# Constraint for 2 foreign keys to have same secondary column value

Tags: mysql, database-design, constraint

Suppose I have a table such as Users that has a id and a company_id
I want to make a 2nd table that has pairs of user id's ex: (primary_key_id, user1_id, user2_id).

The user id's must be in the same company for these pairs of users.

How can I add a constraint to my database to require this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a unique constraint across `company_id` and `id` of the `User` table, then create two foreign keys that reference them.

> Syntax for MySQL

```
CREATE TABLE `User` (
  id int PRIMARY KEY,
  company_id int,
  UNIQUE KEY (company_id, id)
);

CREATE TABLE UserPair (
  company_id int,
  user1_id int,
  user2_id int,
  PRIMARY KEY (company_id, user1_id, user2_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (company_id, user1_id) REFERENCES `User` (company_id, id),
  FOREIGN KEY (company_id, user2_id) REFERENCES `User` (company_id, id)
);
```

```
INSERT `User` (id, company_id) VALUES
(1,1),
(2,1),
(3,2);
```

```
INSERT UserPair (company_id, user1_id, user2_id) VALUES(1,1,2);
```

```
INSERT UserPair (company_id, user1_id, user2_id) VALUES(1,1,3);
-- Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e6d9b1ada8c4f28ab6b484e0285e60b5) (for SQL Server, which is slightly different syntax)

The constraint fails because there is only a single `company_id` which each foreign key uses, but one of the corresponding parent rows has a different `company_id`.

Comment: This is the way.